# GWT with Manifest not working as expected on second load

Tags: gwt, html, resources, manifest

I've wasted 2 days trying to understand why my manifest was not working using GWT in Eclipse. Actually, the answer was in the question. For some reasons, GWT's Jetty is not working well with html5 manifest.

On the first run, you can see the browser downloading every image/resource nicely but... if you update an image in a folder, update the manifest and you reload the page.. that doesn't work whatsoever! The old image still appears.

Looking at the log, you can see that the image has been downloaded again but that's it. No way to get to it.

I miserably failed trying to use swapCache and listeners but actually there is no need for because when I deployed it in a tomcat installation... magic ! It WORKED !

I have a sneaky suspicion that the embedded jetty is caching the image and not really checking if it has changed. Do you know how to fix that in GWT's Jetty ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Plugin for Eclipse needs to be notified manually of changes when using the embedded Jetty server, it cannot detect changed resources automatically. To inform the plugin that it needs to check for changes click the button highlighted in the following image.

[image: Reload web server button location]